# Submit button only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

I am trying to use framework 7 to create a mobile phone application. In the application I have a form that I would like the user to submit multiple times however the submit button seems to stop working after the first time. Any suggestions?

```html
<form method="GET" class="form-ajax-submit" id="my-form">
  <div class="userInput">
    <input class="title" name="title" placeholder="Title your memory">
    <textarea class="newmemory" name="newmemory" id="newmemory" rows="40" cols="30"></textarea>
    <div class="tags">
      <h4>Add some tags to this memory:</h4>
      <textarea class="tags" name="tags" id="tags" rows="2" cols="30" placeholder="Seperate tags with a comma          For example: mom, dad, grandma"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="convert-form-to-data"><input type="submit" id="rememberbtn" value="Remember this for me!"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
$$('.convert-form-to-data').on('click', function() {
  mainView.router.navigate('/memories/');
  var formData = app.form.convertToData('#my-form');
  cards.push(app.form.convertToData('#my-form'));
});
```

Comment: To raise the click event on the `.convert-form-to-data` div you need to click the submit button, which in turn submits the form and transfers the page...

Comment: You don't prevent the form from submitting. Instead of adding a click handler to the button, add a `submit` handler to the form, then `return false;` at the end.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Isn't that what I am doing right now? If not how would I do that?

Comment: @ChrisG How would I go about adding a submit handler?

Comment: `$('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault; /* your code here... */ });`

Comment: Based on your suggestion I changed it to this however it still only fires once:  $('#my-form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault;                              
       mainView.router.navigate('/memories/');
    var formData = app.form.convertToData('#my-form');
    cards.push(app.form.convertToData('#my-form'));                                    
})

Comment: I think mainView.router.navigate is refreshing the page. But it's hard to tell without a working example.